# Eclipse ADT Debug session automatically closing

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adt

Whilst stepping through my code (from a breakpoint), after a short time, e.g. 30 seconds my debug session is always closing and the application resumed.

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance,

Platform:
Android 2.2
ADT 10.0.0
DDMS 10.0.0
Eclipse Helios
64-bit linux